# Knowbe4 phishing test emails blocked by Fortimail

Tags: microsoft-office

We use Office 365 and Fortimail (emails received by O365 are sent to Fortimail for analysis and if they pass, they're sent back to O365).

We are trying to run phishing tests with Knowbe4.  Unfortunately, the emails are blocked by Fortimail with this message:
FortiGuard-WebFilter identified URI: http://gmail.net-login.com/XYWNr0aW9uPWxNsaWNrJnyVybD1olbY3eVyZMA==, category: Phishing, id: 61.

Is there a way to white list all the URL's that Knowbe4 use in Fortimail so that they're not considered spam ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should have gotten a document from KnowBe4, that covers the following:

> If you do have a cloud-based spam filter:
>
> Whitelist by email header in your mail server and whitelist by IP address or hostname in your spam filter.
> If you are unable to whitelist our IP addresses, you can whitelist our mail server hostnames instead.

Also, for 365 users they have special instructions:

> For Microsoft 365 users, we recommend our Direct Message Injection (DMI) feature. DMI eliminates the need for whitelisting by creating a secure link between your KnowBe4 console and your Microsoft 365 Account.

KnowBe4's support page has more information and the lists of addresses you should be using.